# Need to perform RequestBasedLogging

Tags: logback, slf4j

I have a need to implement request based logging.
Based on header - log-level-header.

In my code, I am using JAX-RS and have implemented ContainerRequestFilter.

```
@Override
public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {

    String log_level = context.getHeaderString("log-level-header");
    //translate to actual log level
    Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(logLevelToSet);
}
```

I am using Logback and slf4j API. 
The problem is that i am setting the log level to the RootLogger which is a singleton and hence ends up modifying the log level across application.

Instead I intend to change the log level for a particular thread (RequestBasedLogging). Is it achievable and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is achievable via [TurboFilters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) and [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html). The code in [MDCFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/MDCFilter.html) should be helpful as well.

The key is to understand MDC.